# Write a function that takes an array of int and returns sum of even and odd values as a array. (Read full in Description)

Tags: java, arrays

Write a function that takes an array as input and returns an array of 2 numbers. The returned array contains the sum of even numbers and sum of odd numbers from the input.

If any of the input is null it should be treated as an empty array

### Example:

Input:
[30, 18, 2, 83, 20, 71]
Output:
[70, 154]

Input:
[14, 11, 10, 67, 41]
Output:
[24, 119]

Input:
[36, 24, -82, 29, 44, -3, -100, -5, 49]
Output:
[-78, 70]

This is my progress so far but some of the test cases were failed and I couldn't get full marks. Any help would be appreciated.

PS I'm a beginner

```
//Function 
public int[] getSumOfEvensAndOdds(int[] array) {
    // Student code begins here
    int[] res = {0,0};
    int len = array.length;

    if(array == null){
        return res;
    }
    
    //logic
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
            res[0] += array[i];
        } else if(array[i] % 2 != 0){
            res[1] += array[i];
        } else{
            res[0] += 0;
            res[1] += 0;
        }
    }
    
    return res;
    
}
```

Comment: Which test cases did your code fail on?

Comment: That's not known to us. I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: What do you expect from `res[0] += 0;`?

Comment: @Pshemo or in what cases is that expected to execute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test for `null` **before** you try to get the `array.length`. And, you only need an `if-else` in the loop (a number is even or odd, there isn't a tertiary state). Like,

```
public int[] getSumOfEvensAndOdds(int[] array) {
    // Student code begins here
    int[] res = { 0, 0 };

    if (array == null) {
        return res;
    }
    int len = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            res[0] += array[i];
        } else {
            res[1] += array[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

**or** even without an `if` in the loop at all like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int n = Math.abs(array[i] % 2);
    res[n] += array[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems easy now. :D

Comment: On a point of specification, it is wrong to say that `null` input contains zero odds and zero evens. It should simply be an invalid input, and throw an exception accordingly. But if this is the hoop you have to jump through...

Comment: @Elliott the "or even" only works for positive array elements.

Comment: Or even: `if (array != null) { for (int value : array) { res[value % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1] += value; } }`

Answer (score 0):

try out this one

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SumOfEvenOdd {
    public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arr1 = { 30, 18, 2, 83, 20, 71 };
    System.out.println(String.format("array1: %s,  output %s",
        Arrays.toString(arr1),
        Arrays.toString(getSumOfEvensAndOdds(arr1))));
    int[] arr2 = { 14, 11, 10, 67, 41 };
    System.out.println(String.format("array2: %s,  output %s",
        Arrays.toString(arr2),
        Arrays.toString(getSumOfEvensAndOdds(arr2))));
    int[] arr3 = { 36, 24, -82, 29, 44, -3, -100, -5, 49 };
    System.out.println(String.format("array3: %s,  output %s",
        Arrays.toString(arr3),
        Arrays.toString(getSumOfEvensAndOdds(arr3))));
    }

    public static int[] getSumOfEvensAndOdds(int[] arr) {
        int[] res = new int[2];
        if (arr == null)
            return res;
        for (int i : arr) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                res[0] += i;
            } else {
                res[1] += i;
           }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

> Output

```
array1: [30, 18, 2, 83, 20, 71],  output [70, 154]
array2: [14, 11, 10, 67, 41],  output [24, 119]
array3: [36, 24, -82, 29, 44, -3, -100, -5, 49],  output [-78, 70]
```

Comment: Down-voted for no explanation. In what way will result be different from result of question code?